# json_encode turns array into an object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am have created a 'liking' system for a site but I'm having a bit of trouble with json_encode and json_decode. I use arrays to store who has liked a post, so I need these 2 functions to make it storable, but for some reason it sometimes saves an object to the database:

`{"1":"admin"}`

instead of an Array (which I want):

`["admin"]`

This is my code:

```
if ($liked_by == NULL){ $liked_by = Array(); }
if (! in_array($user, $liked_by)){
  $liked_by[] = $user;
  $likes = $row['likes']+1;
  $liked_by = json_encode($liked_by);
  mysql_query("UPDATE $stream SET liked_by = '$liked_by' WHERE id = ".$id, $db)
    or die(mysql_error($db));
  mysql_query("UPDATE $stream SET likes = '$likes' WHERE id = ".$id, $db)
    or die(mysql_error($db));
} else{
  if(($liker = array_search($user, $liked_by)) !== false) {
    unset($liked_by[$liker]);
  }
  $likes = $row['likes']-1;
  $liked_by = json_encode($liked_by);
  mysql_query("UPDATE $stream SET liked_by = '$liked_by' WHERE id = ".$id, $db)
    or die(mysql_error($db));
  mysql_query("UPDATE $stream SET likes = '$likes' WHERE id = ".$id, $db)
    or die(mysql_error($db));
}
```

Sorry about using deprecated mysql functions...

I'm just not sure what's happening.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats fine since you can get it back as `json_decode($data,true)` as an array

Comment: The zero index seems missing in your example, which could cause the problem, the reason may be your `unset()` call. A simple solution would be to call [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) right before encoding.

Comment: ^ see [`json_dencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s documentation.

Comment: This doesn't happen all the time, it just seems to happen at random moments.

Comment: @Sirko how do you mean?

Comment: `$liked_by = json_encode($liked_by);` => `$liked_by = json_encode( array_values($liked_by) );`. It's kind of a dirty workaround, though.

Comment: why did you not have normalized your database ? Also, in an update statement, you can change multiple columns in one row in one query. Fe `("UPDATE $stream SET liked_by = '$liked_by', likes = '$likes' WHERE id = ".$id, $db)`. Also there is no excuses for using deprecated functions. Sorry

Comment: If you think your solution would work you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty That works great! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as

```
json_decode($data,true);
```

where `$data` is the saved data from DB.

The above will return an array and you can manipulate it for further operation.